# "java.util.NoSuchElementException No line found" after program run

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I'm making a console based 'operating system' which can run some programs. However after a program is run the scanner fails and can no longer accept new commands - the program crashes. Here is an example of the faulty code.

The command input for 1 program in the main class

```
while (!userInput.equals("kill")) {
                        System.out.print("DukeOS/menus/programs>");
userInput = input.nextLine();
switch (userInput) {
case "PrimeTester":
    while (!userInput.equals("cncl")
            && !userInput.equals("kill")) {
        System.out.print("DukeOS/menus/programs/PrimeTester>");
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        switch (userInput) {
        case "load":
            PrimeTester primeTester = new PrimeTester();
            System.out.println("PrimeTester successfully initialised.");
            Scanner checkInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an integer that you want to test for primality:");
            long testInput = checkInput.nextLong();
            primeTester.primeTest(testInput);
            checkInput.close();
            break;
```

And the program executed in a separate class

```
class PrimeTester {
void primeTest(long testInput) {
    long tester = (long) Math.sqrt(testInput);
    System.out.println("Testing...");
    while (true) {
        tester -= 2;
        if (tester < 2) {
            System.out.println("The number " + testInput + " is prime!");
            break;
        }
        if ((testInput % tester) == 0) {
            System.out
                    .println("The number " + testInput + " is composite!");
            System.out.println("It is divisible by " + testInput / tester
                    + ".");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Simple explanations would be great, I'm a bit of a java noob :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all probability, your program has a `Scanner` open, at the time your prime-tester application opens it's own. Both your scanners are reading from `System.in`. Now after your program closes, you close the *prime-tester `Scanner`*. Here comes your error:

Closing that `Scanner`, you also close the underlying `System.in`. This is why your first `Scanner` will now fail: it's input stream has just been closed!

The solution should be to try to (re)use only one `Scanner`.

Comment: Is there a way to reopen the input stream without redoing `new Scanner(System.in)`?

Comment: The best way is to just do `new Scanner(System.in)` just once, and take care to not close it. In particular: try to get rid of this line: `Scanner checkInput = new Scanner(System.in);`.

Comment: Ok, in the end I just removed `checkInput.close()` rather than not opening a second Scanner. It worked fine. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great! Perhaps that is the best solution:-) Just be careful not to close it, there is no `.open()` for `Scanner` (I checked the javadocs;-).